# Why is my Protobuf message being truncated only when sent from a Windows box to a Linux box?

Tags: python, linux, windows, ubuntu, protocol-buffers

I'm using a plain-jane, dumbed down, synchronous Python server and client combination to send Google Protobuf messages over a TCP connection. The server is running on Windows XP using Python 2.5.4 and Google Protobuf 2.4.1. The client is running on an Ubuntu 12.04 Server using Python 2.7.3 and Google Protobuf 2.4.1.

When I run the server on the XP machine and try to talk to it using the client on the Ubuntu machine, the server parses the request message just fine and sends the response message just fine, but the client encounters an `google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Truncated message` error.

If I run both the client and the server on the XP machine I don't encounter the error, nor do I encounter the error if I run the server on the Ubuntu machine and the client on the XP machine.

It seems like it *might* have something to do with the actual Protobuf message itself... if I use a very simple Protobuf message like the one in the example below things seem to work fine. However, once I start using the actual Protobuf message we're using in production I see the error. It still seems weird though that I **only** get the error when the server's on Windows and the client's on Ubuntu.

Any ideas what might be going on?! Given some environment constraints, I must stick with Python 2.5 on the Windows machine and Google Protobuf 2.4.1.

example protobuf.proto

```
message Foo {
  required string name = 1;
}

message Bar {
  required string name = 1;
}

message Sucka {
  required string name = 1;
  repeated Foo    foos = 2;
  repeated Bar    bars = 3;
}

message Result {
  enum Exception {
    NONE    = 0;
    GENERIC = 1;
  }

  required Exception exception = 1;
  optional string    message   = 2;
  optional Sucka     sucka     = 3;
}
```

server.py

```
import signal, socket, struct

from protobuf import Sucka, Result

class TestServer():
  def __init__(self, host = '0.0.0.0', port = 9989):
    self.host = host
    self.port = port

    self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.socket.bind((self.host, self.port))
    self.socket.listen(1)

    self.running = False
    self.conn    = None

    self.run()

  def run(self):
    def handle_exit(signum, stack):
      print 'Shutting down server in response to signal %s' % (str(signum))
      self.running = False

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT,  handle_exit)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handle_exit)

    print 'Waiting on a connection'
    self.running = True

    while self.running:
      try:
        self.conn, addr = self.socket.accept()

        print 'Connection from:', addr

        size_t = self.conn.recv(4)
        size   = struct.unpack('!I', size_t)
        data   = self.conn.recv(size[0])

        if not data:
          raise Exception('No data... did the client close the connection?')

        result = Result()

        try:
          sucka = Sucka()
          sucka.ParseFromString(data)

          result.exception = result.NONE
          result.sucka.CopyFrom(sucka)
        except Exception, ex:
          print str(ex)
          result.exception = result.GENERIC
          result.message   = 'Exception: %s' % (str(ex))
        finally:
          if self.conn: self.conn.close()

    self.socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  s = TestServer()
```

client.py

```
import socket, struct, time

from protobuf import Sucka, Result

class TestClient():
  def __init__(self, sucka, host = '127.0.0.1', port = 9989):
    self.addr = (host, port)
    self.__call(sucka)

  def __call(self, sucka):
    size   = sucka.ByteSize()
    size_t = struct.pack('!I', size)

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    sock.connect(self.addr)
    sock.send(size_t)
    sock.send(sucka.SerializeToString())

    size_t = sock.recv(4)
    size   = struct.unpack('!I', size_t)
    data   = sock.recv(size[0])

    result = Result()
    result.ParseFromString(data)

    if result.exception != Result.NONE:
      raise Exception(result.message)

    print str(result.sucka)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  import sys, os
  sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

  from protobuf import Sucka

  sucka      = Sucka()
  sucka.name = 'testing'

  for i in range(0, 25):
    foo      = sucka.foos.add()
    foo.name = 'foo-%i-tester' % i

  for i in range(0, 25):
    bar      = sucka.bars.add()
    bar.name = 'bar-%i-tester' % i

  c = TestClient(sucka, '127.0.0.1', 9989)
```

Comment: In python, does `conn.recv` read *exactly* that many bytes? (sorry, I'm not a python person, but incorrect socket reading is the *usual* cause here) - also - have you logged what was sent and what arrived, and compared them?

Comment: `conn.recv` only receives _up to_ the given number of bytes -- it may receive less, in which case you need to call `recv` again to receive more.  I'd guess this is the problem -- you can verify by adding some print statements to find out how many bytes you are actually sending and receiving at each end.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. It indeed had to do with `recv`. I added a `while loop` to keep `recv`ing until the length of data received matched what was expected. If one of you want to post an actual answer to the question I'll accept it.